# Matlab - How can I write the values to an excel in a nested for loop

Tags: matlab

I have an Image which is 1944(R) x 2592 (C). I would like to take one column at a time; treating each column as an Image and calculate how many pixels among each row of that column contains value > half(max) value of that column. Those number of pixels are to be written to the excel sheet corresponding to it's respective column.

Image: [the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MvsAKaAfj-Z2ZGZ0NCXzliZE0/edit)

Here is what I have tried so far, I am not able to write it successfully.

```
 clc;
    sig = rgb2gray(imread('1.bmp')); % read in the image.
    % imshow(sig);
    ArraySize = size(sig); %1944(R) x 2592 (C)
    [maxval, maxloc] = max(sig(:)); % Gives the max and the location
    maxval; % max value
    [maxloc_row, maxloc_col] = ind2sub(size(sig), maxloc); % convert logical 

    %-------------------------------------------------------------------%
    % Count pixels through each column > half(max) value of that column
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------%

    newfilename = 'Results.csv'; % write new values to .csv files
    Array =  zeros(2592,2);
    % % R = Array(:,1);
    % y = Array(:,2);
    for a = 1: 2592% maxloc_row =  635 maxloc_col = 1094 
       [a_maxval, a_maxloc] = max(sig(:,a)); % search max among every column.
       % maxloc is the row at which maxval is.
       newval = a_maxval/2; % averaged max value
    % New structure for find width
             x = 0; 
             x = Array(:, 1);
             for b = 1: 1944 % maxloc_row =  635 maxloc_col = 1094
    %                R = b;
                if sig(b,a) > newval
                    x=x+1;
                end      
             end % End row search
              x;
    % y = x*(2.2); % pixels into microns
              output = [num2cell(x)];
             xlswrite(newfilename, output);
    end % End column search
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `csvwrite` can write data to csv file. Here's what you can try:

place `output = [];` somewhrere at top, says below `clc;`

then, replace

`output = [num2cell(x)];` with `output = [output x];`

and

`xlswrite(newfilename, output);` with `csvwrite(newfilename, output);` but place it at the end of program because `output` has all `x` inside.

I have tried and it works.